# collapse input cell in ein

Tags: code-folding, ein

I am using `ein` with emacs 25-3.
As some of the cells I am writing contain classes definitions, I would like to be able to collapse them to show only the first line.
I know output cells can be toggled on and off with `C-c C-e` But I need to the input one to collapse.

I have posted the suggestion as an issue in the ein project on github just now: [link to issue](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook/issues/282).   I woder if there is a way to work around it.

**edit:**
I meanwhile added the code folding mode `origami`.
It folds all the cells and in combination with `hydra` I can get it to fold cells and classes and functions. I will update this questions after I work with it for a bit.

Comment: In [here](https://youtu.be/OB9vFu9Za8w?t=2160) the maintainer shows that he is able to fold. don't know how though. It doesn't seem to be part of ein.